# ng serve --open error You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: angular, npm

I am beginner at angular js so I tried steps mention in [Angular quickstart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart). When I run **ng serve --open** I get below error

( I use windows 7 )

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 11 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 15.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.26 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./ansi-html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> #!/bin/sh
| basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
|
i ?wdm?: Failed to compile.
c
```

I re-intalled npm and angular still same error.

**node version = 10.10.0**

**npm version = 6.4.1**

**angular CLI = 6.2.1**

I do not understand what exactly reason of error and how I can fix it so I can continue with rest of the tutorial.

**Below is ansi-html file**

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/ansi-html/bin/ansi-html" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/ansi-html/bin/ansi-html" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Comment: can you paste the content of ansi-html?

Comment: The `angularjs` tag is for Angular 1, so I've removed that tag for you

Comment: I updated ansi-html in question